# c# Synchronise asynchronous messages processing - TPL Dataflow pipelines

Tags: c#, synchronization, tpl-dataflow

What am I doing:
I have a microservice, part of an order processing system, which constantly consumes order messages from RabbitMQ and I need to temporary keep them in my microservice DB, until they are handled (accepted/declined). The order messages are forwarded to a TPL Dataflow pipeline, which has two branches.

The first one being for processing 'created' orders.
When an order is created I perform some operations, such as statistics for the order, validations, persisting in to DB and notifying the user through SignalR. (I have 5 blocks for this branch, and some include I/O network calls).

The second branch (2 blocks) is for accepted/declined orders. When I receive an order with status accepted/declined I need to remove it from my DB and also notify the user through SignalR.

The message for 'created' and 'accepted/declined' order differs only in its status property.
The forwarding to each of the two branches happens through TPL Dataflow's link predicate, based on the order status.

My problem:
Sometimes a message for declined/accpeted order arrives 50-150 ms after the message for the same order being created. Usually, 50-150 ms are a lot of time in computing, but the first dataflow branch is dependent on external calls to other services, which might cause a delay in the processing.

I want to make sure that I have fully processed the message with status 'created' and only after that to process the message for the same order being 'accepted/declined'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
            var executionOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, // potentially would be increased
                BoundedCapacity = 50
            };
            var deserialize = new TransformBlock<OrderStatus, Order>(o =>
            {
                return new Order { Status = o };
            }, executionOptions);

            #region Creted order
            var b11 = new TransformBlock<Order, Order>(async o =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(15); // do something
                return o;
            }, executionOptions);
            var b12 = new TransformBlock<Order, Order>(async o =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(15); // do something
                return o;
            }, executionOptions);
            var b13 = new TransformBlock<Order, Order>(async o =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(15);
                Console.WriteLine("Saved In DB");
                return o;
            }, executionOptions);
            var b14 = new ActionBlock<Order>(async o =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5);
                Console.WriteLine("SignalR order created");
            }, executionOptions);
            #endregion

            #region Accepted/Declined
            var b21 = new ActionBlock<Order>(async o =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5);
                Console.WriteLine("Deleted from DB");
            }, executionOptions);
            var b22 = new ActionBlock<Order>(async o =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5);
                Console.WriteLine("SignalR order deleted");
            }, executionOptions);
            #endregion

            var deleteFromDbAndSignalRInParallelJob = new List<ITargetBlock<Order>> { b21, b22 }.CreateGuaranteedBroadcastBlock();

            deserialize.LinkTo(b11, linkOptions, x => x.Status == OrderStatus.Created);
            b11.LinkTo(b12, linkOptions);
            b12.LinkTo(b13, linkOptions);
            b13.LinkTo(b14, linkOptions);

            deserialize.LinkTo(deleteFromDbAndSignalRInParallelJob, linkOptions);

            deserialize.Post(OrderStatus.Created);
            Thread.Sleep(30); // delay between messaged
            deserialize.Post(OrderStatus.Declined);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Order
    {
        public OrderStatus Status { get; init; }
    }
    enum OrderStatus
    {
        Created = 1,
        Declined = 2
    }
    public static class DataflowExtensions
    {
        public static ITargetBlock<T> CreateGuaranteedBroadcastBlock<T>(this IEnumerable<ITargetBlock<T>> targets)
        {
            var targetsList = targets.ToList();
            return new ActionBlock<T>(async item =>
            {
                var tasks = targetsList.Select(t => t.SendAsync(item));
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 100 });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample with simplified models and logic simulating that the 'created' order branch is taking more time to complete.
The output is:

- SignalR order deleted
- Deleted from DB
- Saved In DB
- SignalR order created

Comment: Low tech solution is keep the hash / dictionary of currently processing orders, put them in a queue until finished, once finished pop any other order off the queue. rinse and repeat. Obviously there are many other variants of similar logic

Comment: Another low tech solution is just to delay sending the order `Accepted/Declined` message until your done processing the order

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Where's the predicate and the accepted/declined blocks?

Comment: In any case, TPL Dataflow ensures the order of messages. That means that each block in a single pipeline won't see `deleted` before `created`, as long as the messages are posted in the correct order to the pipeline's head. If you had a *single* pipeline, with the "Created" blocks before the `Accepted/Declined`, you could ensure that the `Created` blocks would always be processed first. The `Created` blocks would simply forward `Accepted` messages to the next block. That's similar to [Railway Oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/)